# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '..' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

The problem is in variable hour when I try use in the `CmdString` is throwing an exception. I don't understand why is throwing the exception when variable hour is string. How can I solve this problem. What I'm missing here.

```
string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbSystem"].ConnectionString;
string CmdString = string.Empty;

DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string hour = time.Hour.ToString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    string folderName = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string folder = Path.Combine(FOLDER_FOR_BACKUP_FILES);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(FOLDER_FOR_BACKUP_FILES);

    CmdString = @"declare @fileName varchar(100); declare @dbName varchar(100); declare @fileDate varchar(20); set @fileName = '" + folder + @"\'; set @dbName = 'DbSystem'; set @fileDate = convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 105); set @fileName = @fileName + @dbName + ' ' + @fileDate + '-' + " + hour + @" + '.bak'; backup database @dbName to disk = @fileName;";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("*");
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: you should use a parameterized query instead of building your command string like this due to SQL Injection! look at the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `CONVERT` your hour to `VARCHAR`:

```
@fileDate + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), " + hour + @") + '.bak';
```

Though `hour` is a string in the application side, when it's executed by the SQL Server, it's an `INT`. So you need to implicitly include a `CONVERT` function.

Answer (score 1):

Because hour is string now. You can change CmdString  to

```
CmdString = @"declare @fileName varchar(100); declare @dbName varchar(100); declare @fileDate varchar(20); set @fileName = '" + folder + @"\'; set @dbName = 'DbSystem'; set @fileDate = convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 105); set @fileName = @fileName + @dbName + ' ' + @fileDate + '-' + '" + hour + @"' + '.bak'; backup database @dbName to disk = @fileName;";
```